# Converting a string to an enum without warnings

Tags: java, generics, enums

I'm writing some kind of deserializer using reflection and am banging my head with Java generics. I have:

- an object `Object object`,
- a reference to a field from this object (`java.lang.reflect.Field field`) that is for an enum (`field.getType().isEnum()` returns `true`),
- a string representation of that enum (`String string`)

I can parse the string to the enum and set it in the object with the following code:

```
Class<Enum> enumClass = (Class<Enum>) field.getType();
field.set(object, Enum.valueOf(enumClass, string));
```

However this generates compilation warnings because Enum is a generic type.

If I add a generic (`Enum<?>`) I get a compilation error on the Enum.valueOf call).

Is there a way to get the same result without the generics warnings (or write it in a "nicer" way)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to get the same result without the generics warnings (or write it in a "nicer" way)?

No. Since you're not telling the compiler exactly what the types involved are, because of the raw type use, it cannot be certain of what will happen at runtime and therefore must warn you.

All you can do is suppress the warnings

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
```